# Finding the distance of a point from a line

Tags: geometry

If I have a line formed by points A and B, how can I find the distance of another point from that line. Also, whether that line is clockwise or CCW from point A.
[image]

I'm not really even sure how to get started with this. I know the midpoint of A and B, but after that I am out of my depth.

Would appreciate advice on how to proceed.

Comment: Are you looking for the point/line distance or for the radius of the circumscribed circle by the three points ? Please clarify.

Comment: "whether that line is clockwise or CCW from point A" is meaningless.

Comment: Sorry, my maths is long forgotten (over 30 years ago) and I struggle to describe my requirements. By "clockwise" I mean that if A is at -10, 0 and B at 10, 0, then clockwise from A is anything above the x axis, and CCW anything below. Conversely, if A is at 10,0 and B at -10,0 then clockwise would be anything BELOW the line. (I can't think of another way to describe it other than clockwise and CCW)

Comment: FYI, the method I used was to take the midpoint of A and B and calculate the angle and distance to Z, from that I could calculate r. Determining whether it was clockwise (above the line) was calculated by comparing the vector of AB to AZ (if AZ is between AB and AB + 180 then it is clockwise). The answers below helped me to visualize the solution :-)

Comment: You still did not clarify "the point/line distance or the radius".

Comment: What I mean is that if you have a line AB and a point Z, what is the minimum distance of Z from any point on line AB (or alternatively, if A, B and Z are points of a circle, what is the distance from the midpoint of AB to the curve (at 90 deg.)

Comment: What do you mean by alternatively ? These are two different questions.

Comment: For my purposes (estimating the size of a curve converted from a line) it doesn't need to be exact, so I really just needed the quickest way to calculate it, so I would have been happy with a method to fine either solution

Comment: Hem, what do you call "it" ??? Please stop the ambiguity.

Comment: "It" means the solution to the minimum distance of Z from any point on line AB (or alternatively, if A, B and Z are points of a circle, the distance from the midpoint of AB to the curve (at 90 deg.))

Comment: For the last time, these are two very different things so that "alternatively" makes little sense.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you are saying. There are two alternatives. I was happy with a solution to either of the alternatives.

Comment: Your question sounds like "tell me the perimeter of a triangle or alternatively the volume of a sphere".

Comment: I'm not sure where you get that from. In my image above I clearly ask for "r ". Anyway the question has already been answered by two posters, so this thread seems unproductive.

Comment: Why did you accept an answer that does *not* compute $r$ then ???

Comment: The accepted answer provided me a solution to calculate a value similar to r (for a curve that passes through A and B, and C is the extent of that curve - the alternative in point 2 above). While I didn't use their actual method, their explanation allowed me to create a solution, which I detailed above.

Comment: I pity you for your mind-blindness. One of these constructions is not at all what you want.

Comment: The solution I implemented works just fine for our testers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a better method:

[image: enter link description here]

Let $A$ be at $(0,2)$, $B$ be at $(3, -2)$ , and $C$ be at $(7, -3)$.

The distance from $A$ to $B$ is $\sqrt{(-2-2)^2+(3-0)^2} = 5$. Let $AD$ be $x$ and $BD$ be $5-x$. You can then use find $AC$ and $BC$ and use the Pythagorean theorem to find $x$, and after that, find how long the perpendicular is.

Comment: Better than what ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Better than the OP's method.

Comment: Thanks, both your method and g-cab's helped me to understand what I was trying to do and resolve the issue.

Comment: The OP is not describing any method, but two distinct problems. You are solving the second problem.

Comment: *Yves Daoust*'s comment is pertinent, this method might be simpler for computing the distance, but not its sign.

Answer (score 1):

[image: punto_linea_1]

Take the vectors
$$
{\bf v} = \mathop {BA}\limits^ \to  \quad \;{\bf z} = \mathop {BZ}\limits^ \to  
$$

Compute the unitary vector $\bf t$ parallel to $\bf v$
$$
{\bf t} = {{\bf v} \over {\left| {\bf v} \right|}}
$$
and the unitary vector $\bf n$ normal to it
$$
{\bf n} = \left( {t_y , - t_x } \right)
$$

You can see that with the signs chosen for $\bf n$, the sign of
$\bf n \times \bf t$ is positive, according to the right hand rule, 
that is the axes $(n,t)$ are oriented same as $(x,y)$.

Now the dot products 
$$
\left( {{\bf z} \cdot {\bf n},\;{\bf z} \cdot {\bf t}} \right)
$$
will give you the coordinates of $\bf z$ in that system, and their signs the 
position of $\bf z$ in the relative quadrants.
${\bf z} \cdot {\bf n}$ is the distance of $Z$ from the line $AB$, with the sign
corresponding to the direction of $\bf n$.

Comment: Thanks, both your method and toby-mak's helped me to understand what I was trying to do and resolve the issue. Chose toby-mak's as the answer because I followed it better.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{AB}{\|AB\|}\times AZ$$ gives you the distance with a positive or negative sign depending on which side $Z$ lies.